# Creating even more photorealistic rendering of this 3d print I actually made

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I hope this isn't too open ended, but in the style of [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108511/mesh-modeling-review-black-hole-cannot-select-face-joining-subdivisions) I found on here I figured I'd go for it.

I run a 3d printer in a hospital, and as a result I 3d printed this model showcasing the work done on a particular patient:
[image]

I've blacked out the name of our hospital, though I think it'd be hard to identify the patient just based on the image.

Anyhow, as a side project, I've been trying to use Blender to see if I could "fake" that photo.  I.e. get a rendered image to the point where the casual viewer didn't know it wasn't real.

So far, after following BlenderGuru's [tutorial on wood found here](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/photorealistic-wood), this is my best attempt:
[image]

So my (hopefully not too open ended) question to you all is:  what changes would you make [to this file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnsEucAtFS_SgZUtHsVi8Fo8BGtpaQ?e=2BxjzY) if it were up to you to make more realistic?  Specifically the look of the clear plastic or the lighting.  I'm not too worried that the wood grain is slightly different than the one on my desk.

Comment: My 2cts: Add volume absorption and roughness to the clear plastic. Use filmic for color management and an indoor HDRI for lighting (https://hdrihaven.com/hdris/category/?c=indoor&o=popular) + perhaps some manually placed lights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everything is to nice.  render at a lower resolution, and use the compositor to make it look like it was taken with a cheap camera.  make the lighting more blown out.